# Can I recognize insecticides in tea?

Tags: tea, shopping

I am a tea fan (especially Chinese teas but Japanese as well)
I found many places on the Internet to buy teas. Good quality and natural tasting.

What is important to me is the quality in term of taste (natural, without any aromatic addition) but also in term of ecology (I would like to avoid as much as possible insecticides and other endocrine disruptors).

So far, might be a bit surprising, but I found very good quality *longjin* (green tea) and some *da hong pao* (black tea) on Aliexpress for excellent rate regarding other more "premium" platform...but I am not sure how to know if what they call "bio" is a "real" control in term of insecticide.

**So my question is** : is there any method - achievable at home- to know the "percentage" or any trace of insecticide in a tea that I bought from the internet ? Like something that I would put in my brew that tells me if any kind of chemicals is present ?

Comment: Hi, tea is indeed fascinating. I had some trouble understanding what you are asking. Note that we don't take shopping questions in the sense of recommending which store to buy from. Also, we don't take price-building questions (how come that food X costs Y). Maybe you could clarify what exact problem you are trying to solve, besides deciding where to buy your tea, so we can understand better how we can help? Objectively answerable subquestions that lead you to your buying decisions would also be OK, such as the meaning of tea-specific terms, for example.

Comment: Hi, Thank you, I edited my question to be more clear

Comment: @rumtscho : is it more clear now ?

Comment: If you have quite a lot of money to spare you could have a gas chromatograph. Somewhat more affordable but still not cheap would be hiring the use of someone else's gas chromatograph. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_chromatography

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer - I don't know for sure.

However, I doubt there is a dipstick or any other "do at home" test that would allow you to quickly identify if insecticides are present. This is because insecticides have [quite a large range of chemical types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insecticide#Synthetic_insecticides), with differing amounts/concentrations for their effective range and different stabilities once applied, making it more or less impossible to test for them all quickly and easily.  There are labs around that can test for types of insecticidal residues, particularly the [organophosphate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organophosphate) ones, as these are particularly nasty to life in general; but I can't see any quick tests that don't cost a small fortune and require a set up lab to run them.

Many of the commonly used ones are derived from natural sources (e.g. [pyrethrins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrethrin) - you will probably find these in your home bug spray canister), but are now made synthetically, and I think are considered "organic" (as in organic farming; they are certainly chemically organic [carbon based]).  These are effective at very low concentrations and don't last long outside.

In general (in the Western world at least), farms that produce things for consumption have mandated stand-down periods after spraying, which lower effective concentrations of insecticides and other applied chemicals to levels that are deemed safe by the local authorities. What these levels are depend on the country and are often tested for in the supply chain to ensure that consumers are protected. I can't say whether your sources adhere to any such rules however.